# Reading session/cookies from WSGI

Tags: python, session, wsgi

Is there any way to retrieve sessions right from the WSGI (using a middleware)?
I know that it depends on your SessionMiddleware but I wonder if there are hints to figure out when a session is created.

Answer (score 2):

It's created by the session middle ware. There are no such thing as sessions in http itself. It's usually done by setting a cookie, but can be done in other ways too.

So to answer the question of "when" it is created this is typically done by the session middleware, when it gets a request that does not already have a session cookie in it.

Answer (score 1):

With [Beaker](http://beaker.groovie.org/) (a common WSGI middleware for sessions) you can know whether a session has been [accessed](http://beaker.groovie.org/modules/session.html#beaker.session.SessionObject.accessed) or not.